# Wix Setup Error: Unhandled exception in rundll32.exe

Tags: c#, asp.net, installation, wix

I have created Wix (WindowsInstallerXML) setup for my C# web application. I am getting the following error when I run the .msi file.
Refer the image in link
[**An unhandled microsoft .net framework exception occurred in rundll32.exe**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0Osi.jpg)

Setup is working fine but getting this exception. Any help/ suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check with .NET Framework Setup Verification Tool.
 It will verify the presence of files, directories, registry keys and values for the .NET Framework.  It will also verify that simple applications that use the .NET Framework can be run correctly.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2008/10/13/net-framework-setup-verification-tool-users-guide/